# Pass @IsInt() validation for application/x-www-form-urlencoded request type

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

When I went through **Pipes** documentation I noticed that I can't make `@IsInt()` validation for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** request correctly, cause all values which I passed I receive as string values.

My request data looks like this
[image]

My DTO looks like

```
import { IsString, IsInt } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateCatDto {
    @IsString()
    readonly name: string;

    @IsInt()
    readonly age: number;

    @IsString()
    readonly breed: string;
}
```

Validation pipe contains next code

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

@Pipe()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
    async transform(value, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        const { metatype } = metadata;
        if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
            return value;
        }
        const object = plainToClass(metatype, value);
        const errors = await validate(object);
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
        }
        return value;
    }

    private toValidate(metatype): boolean {
        const types = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
        return !types.find((type) => metatype === type);
    }
}
```

When I debug this pipe I noticed this state
[image]
Where:

- **value** - request body value
- **object** - transformed via **class-transformer** value
- **errors** - error object

As you can see errors tell to us that **age must be an integer number**.

How can I pass `@IsInt()` validation for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** request?

Libraries versions:

- @nestjs/common@4.6.4
- class-transformer@0.1.8
- class-validator@0.8.1

P.S: I also create a [repository](https://github.com/pahan35/nest-js-get-started/tree/how-to-pass-int-validation) where you can run application to test bug. Required branch **how-to-pass-int-validation**

**UPD**: after making changes from accepted answer I faced with problem that I put wrong parsed data to storage. [Recorded example](http://recordit.co/SPrLsRR1Ej)

Is it possible to get well parsed `createCatDto` or what I need to do to save it with correct type structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All values from a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request are always strings.

So, you could do the following:

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsString, IsInt } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateCatDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  @Transform(value => Number.isNan(+value) ? 0 : +value) // this field will be parsed to integer when `plainToClass gets called`
  @IsInt()
  readonly age: number;

  @IsString()
  readonly breed: string;
}
```

Comment: There's only one problem: `Number.isNan()` not exist. We need to use `isNaN()` instead of it.

Comment: There is another one problem: after passing it through validation I got value with string (I put update to my question). Which is the right way of passing correct data to controller?

Comment: According to your validation pipe, you need to return `object` variable, not the `value` variable.

Comment: Is this correct behavior for global pipe changes? I wrote that code based on [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) and just wanna know will be this convenient to return `object` instead of `value`

Comment: I use `object` in projects.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why would you coerce `NaN` to zero? Seems rather arbitrary

Comment: Don't know if this solution was for an old version, but I had to do it like this: `@Transform(({ value }) => isNan(+value) ? 0 : +value )`

Answer (score 5):

Adding @Type(() => Number) resolved the issue for me.

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsInt, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

@IsNotEmpty({ message: '' })
@Type(() => Number)
@IsInt({ message: '' })
project: number;
```

Comment: What is the source of `Type` decorator?

Comment: It comes from class-transformer. I added the imports in the example.

Comment: Better than accepted answer